# What does "will recontact you ..." mean to my CV?

Tags: resume

I recently sent a CV to a technology related company,
and they asked about my previous work experiences in more detail by emails.

After some conversation through emails, their last response was "Thanks, we will recontact you in case we need more info ..."

I guess that means I failed to get the job? Questionable thing is that they were quite interested with my experience.

Comment: It means exactly what it says it means. They haven't made a decision yet. If they need more information to decide whether you're suitable or not then you'll be contacted to clarify the missing information.

Comment: Do the recruiters usually contact the submitter to tell that they are not going to hire him? Or do they remain in silence ?

Comment: ~90% will remain in silence.

Comment: @Jonast92: I think your percentage is way too low.

Comment: @NotMe You're probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thanks, we will recontact you in case we need more info ...
```

Generally this means that they have a list of candidates and if you'll get into the final group of candidates which can be hired then they'll contact you again for more information which will help them decide whether you're suitable or not, possibly by another interview. Right now they got everything they need.

Of course, they might already have made a decision, but there's no point in being negative.

Most employers will not contact you again anyway, just wait and see. If it's a job you really want then you can try to ask them about the status of the recruiting process after some time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

> At present they got required information about you which is enough for
>   them for now

We have 2 issues here

> - They have put your CV on hold because the position you have applied    for is filled and you may listen from them if they need more
>     employees for that position.
> - They put your CV in screening and will get back to you once they feel you are suitable for the position.

In most of the cases if a company is not satisfied or if they don't need to hire they reply as

> Thanks for your interest in us we will surely get back to you when
>   needed or in some other similar way

but in your case this may not be the issue.

So be positive and hope for a positive response all the best.